# Creating constant copies of state variables

Tags: react-native

- I have two state arrays as `processedData` and `processedDataCopy`. I am trying to store copy of `processedData` inside `processedDataCopy`.
- The `processedDataCopy` shouldn't reflect any changes made to `processedData` but as soon as `processedData` data is altered the `processedDataCopy` also changes accordingly to reflect changes made in `processedData`. How should i prevent it from happening?
- I have stored copy of `processedData` in`processedDataCopy` using `setState`inside `componentWillMount()`.
- Simplified version of my code is:

  ```
  export default class ProductsPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
          processedData:[],
          processedDataCopy:[],
          listData:ds.cloneWithRows([]),
        };
      }


    componentWillMount(){
      this.state.processedData.push({multipleKeysinloop:multipleValuesinLoop});
      this.setState({processedDataCopy:this.state.processedData})
      this.setState({listData:this.state.listData.cloneWithRows(this.state.processedData)})
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ListView
         dataSource={this.state.listData}
         renderRow={this.printData.bind(this)}
         />
      );
    }

    printData(){
      //On some action load altered process data else reset to original processedData which is stored in processedDataCopy
      if(processedData is altered)
          this.setState({listData:this.state.listData.cloneWithRows(this.state.processedData)})
      else
          this.setState({listData:this.state.listData.cloneWithRows(this.state.processedDataCopy)})
    }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you needed, https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepcopy

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
this.setState({processedDataCopy:this.state.processedData});
```

you have both of them connected.
If you do so:

```
let processedCopy = this.state.processedData.slice();
this.setState({processedDataCopy: processedCopy});
```

you disconnect the two entities, just taking a full copy of the first one.